# Slide desordenado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou com um problema estou tentando fazer um efeito slide com java , só que esta acontecendo um problema, as imagens que escolhi estão ficando fora do lugar como podem ver a baixo , vou postar os codigos aqui quem poder me ajudar agradeço , Abraços !!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo.png); 
 position:inherit;
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 border-bottom:none;
 margin:auto;     
}

#logo {
 float:left;
 background:url(../imagens/logoc.png);
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 left:155px;
 width:541px;
 height:133px;
}
 
#fundoinicial {
 background-image:url(../imagens/fundoof.png);
 width:1024px;
 height:1185px;
 margin:auto;     
}

#menufundo {
 background:url(../imagens/menu.png);
 position:relative;
 width:1024px;
 height:27px;
 margin:auto;     
}

#ul li a{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-style:normal;
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:0px;
 padding:10px;
    margin:4px 0 0 52px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 float:left;
}

#ul li a:hover{
 text-shadow:0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black; 
 font-size:20px;
    color:black;
}


.rodape {
 background: url(../imagens/rodape.png);
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 width: 1100px;
 height: 99px;
 left: 131px;
 top: 1400px;
}
 
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {background: #000}
a,img {border: none;}
.trs {-webkit-transition:all ease-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all ease-out 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all ease-out 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all ease-out 0.5s;
    transition:all ease-out 0.5s;}  
#slider {
 position: absolute;
 width: 970px;
    height: 342px;
 margin:auto;
 z-index: 0;
 left: -22px;
 top: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #666;
}
#slider a {
 position:relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 10px;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.ativo {opacity: 1!important; filter:alpha(opacity=100)!important;}

/*controladores*/
span {
 background: #999;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 134px;
 width: 43px;
 height: 43px;
 z-index: 5;
}
.next {
 right: 12px;
}
.next:before,.next:after {left: 21px;}
.next:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-42deg);
    top: 5px;
}
.next:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-132deg);
    top: 19px;
}
.next:before,.next:after,.prev:before,.prev:after {content: "";
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
}
.prev {
 left: -12px;
}
.prev:before,.prev:after {left: 18px;}
.prev:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(42deg);
    top: 5px;
}
.prev:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(132deg);
    top: 19px;
}

figure:hover span {opacity: 0.76;filter:alpha(opacity=76);}
    figure {
    max-width: 950px;
    height: 310px;
    position: relative;
 top:60px;
 left:0px;
    margin:0px 0 0 50px;
}

figcaption {
 color: #000;
 font-family: "Kaushan Script","Lato","arial";
 font-size: 22px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #CCC;
 width: 970px;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 bottom: -34px;
 left: -21px;
 line-height: 55px;
 height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Alfatec</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/ico.png" type="imagem/x-png" />
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(../PLANILHAS%20CAIO/projeto/imagens/fundo.jpg);
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function setaImagem(){
     var settings = {
        primeiraImg: function(){
            elemento = document.querySelector("#slider a:first-child");
            elemento.classList.add("ativo");
            this.legenda(elemento);
        },

        slide: function(){
            elemento = document.querySelector(".ativo");

            if(elemento.nextElementSibling){
                elemento.nextElementSibling.classList.add("ativo");
                settings.legenda(elemento.nextElementSibling);
                elemento.classList.remove("ativo");
            }else{
                elemento.classList.remove("ativo");
                settings.primeiraImg();
            }
        },

        proximo: function(){
            clearInterval(intervalo);
            elemento = document.querySelector(".ativo");

            if(elemento.nextElementSibling){
                elemento.nextElementSibling.classList.add("ativo");
                settings.legenda(elemento.nextElementSibling);
                elemento.classList.remove("ativo");
            }else{
                elemento.classList.remove("ativo");
                settings.primeiraImg();
            }
            intervalo = setInterval(settings.slide,4000);
        },

        anterior: function(){
            clearInterval(intervalo);
            elemento = document.querySelector(".ativo");

            if(elemento.previousElementSibling){
                elemento.previousElementSibling.classList.add("ativo");
                settings.legenda(elemento.previousElementSibling);
                elemento.classList.remove("ativo");
            }else{
                elemento.classList.remove("ativo");                     
                elemento = document.querySelector("a:last-child");
                elemento.classList.add("ativo");
                this.legenda(elemento);
            }
            intervalo = setInterval(settings.slide,4000);
        },

        legenda: function(obj){
            var legenda = obj.querySelector("img").getAttribute("alt");
            document.querySelector("figcaption").innerHTML = legenda;
        }
    }

    //chama o slide
    settings.primeiraImg();

    //chama a legenda
    settings.legenda(elemento);

    //chama o slide à um determinado tempo
    var intervalo = setInterval(settings.slide,4000);
    document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click",settings.proximo,false);
    document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click",settings.anterior,false);
}

window.addEventListener("load",setaImagem,false);
</script>


</head>


<body>

<div id="logo"></div><!--div final do logo-->
<div id="topo"></div><!--div final topo-->
<div id="menufundo">

<nav id="ul">    
          <ul>            
           <li><a href="#">Página Inicial   </a></li> 
           <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Áreas de Cobertura</a></li> 
           <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
       </ul>
</nav>
</div>

         
<div id ="fundoinicial">

<figure>
   <span class="trs next"></span>
   <span class="trs prev"></span>

   <div id="slider">
      <a href="#" class="trs"><img src="imagens/img1.jpg" alt="Teste1" width="873" /></a>
      <a href="#" class="trs"><img src="imagens/img2.jpg" alt="Legenda da imagem 2" /></a>
      <a href="#" class="trs"><img src="imagens/img3.jpg" alt="Legenda da imagem 2" /></a>
   </div>

   <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>


<div class="rodape"></div>
</div><!--div final menufundo--> 
        

                            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: #slider a {
 position:absolute;
 width: 970px;
    height: 342px;
 margin:auto;
 left: 60px;
 top: 2px;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}                                                Resolvido !!!!